# Modify array inside of object

Tags: typescript

I want to modify array inside catalog object from the following definition

```
export interface CatalogEntity {
  items: CatalogItem[]
  categories: CatalogCategory[]
  modifiers: CatalogModifier[]
  discounts: CatalogDiscount[]
  taxes: CatalogTax[]
  salesTypes: CatalogSalesType[]
}

export type CatalogEntityKey = keyof CatalogEntity

export const catalog: CatalogEntity = {
  items: [],
  categories: [],
  modifiers: [],
  discounts: [],
  taxes: [],
  salesTypes: [],
}
```

So I created a utility function

```
export type ArrayType<T> = T extends (infer U)[] ? U : never

export function appendEntity<
  K extends CatalogEntityKey, 
  V extends ArrayType<CatalogEntity[K]>
>(key: K, value: V): void {
  const index = catalog[key].findIndex(m => m.id === value.id)
  
  if (index >= 0) catalog[key][index] = value
  else catalog[key].push(value)
}
```

on `catalog[key].push(value)` i get type error

```
Argument of type 'CatalogModifier | CatalogItem | CatalogCategory | CatalogDiscount | CatalogTax | CatalogSalesType' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CatalogModifier & CatalogItem & CatalogCategory & CatalogDiscount & CatalogTax & CatalogSalesType'.
  Type 'CatalogModifier' is not assignable to type 'CatalogModifier & CatalogItem & CatalogCategory & CatalogDiscount & CatalogTax & CatalogSalesType'.
    Type 'CatalogModifier' is missing the following properties from type 'CatalogItem': variants, modifiers, taxests(2345
```

Based on error message above `.push` accepting `CatalogModifier & CatalogItem & ...` instead `CatalogModier | CatalogItem | ...`, how to fix it?

I have try this type assertion

```
catalog[key].push(value as V)
```

But get following error

```
Argument of type 'V' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CatalogModifier & CatalogItem & CatalogCategory & CatalogDiscount & CatalogTax & CatalogSalesType'.
  Type 'ArrayType<CatalogEntity[K]>' is not assignable to type 'CatalogModifier & CatalogItem & CatalogCategory & CatalogDiscount & CatalogTax & CatalogSalesType'.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'CatalogModifier & CatalogItem & CatalogCategory & CatalogDiscount & CatalogTax & CatalogSalesType'.
      Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'CatalogModifier'.
        Type 'CatalogModifier | CatalogItem | CatalogCategory | CatalogDiscount | CatalogTax | CatalogSalesType' is not assignable to type 'CatalogModifier & CatalogItem & CatalogCategory & CatalogDiscount & CatalogTax & CatalogSalesType'.
          Type 'CatalogModifier' is not assignable to type 'CatalogModifier & CatalogItem & CatalogCategory & CatalogDiscount & CatalogTax & CatalogSalesType'.
            Type 'CatalogModifier' is missing the following properties from type 'CatalogItem': variants, modifiers, taxes
              Type 'ArrayType<CatalogEntity[K]>' is not assignable to type 'CatalogModifier'.
                Type 'V' is not assignable to type 'CatalogModifier'.
                  Type 'ArrayType<CatalogEntity[K]>' is not assignable to type 'CatalogModifier'.
                    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'CatalogModifier'.
                      Type 'CatalogModifier | CatalogItem | CatalogCategory | CatalogDiscount | CatalogTax | CatalogSalesType' is not assignable to type 'CatalogModifier'.
                        Property 'options' is missing in type 'CatalogItem' but required in type 'CatalogModifier'.ts(2345)
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about your `Catalog...` types it's difficult to fully say for sure.
But I believe the warning has something to do with the fact that you're extending from a type, and there isn't enough overlap between them...

Below I created a "base type" from which the `Catalog...` types all extend from. I think this provides sufficient overlap of the types for the compiler.

```js
type BaseCategoryType = {
  id: number;
};

type CatalogItem = BaseCategoryType & {};
type CatalogCategory = BaseCategoryType & {};
type CatalogModifier = BaseCategoryType & {};
type CatalogDiscount = BaseCategoryType & {};
type CatalogTax = BaseCategoryType & {};
type CatalogSalesType = BaseCategoryType & {};

export interface CatalogEntity {
  items: CatalogItem[];
  categories: CatalogCategory[];
  modifiers: CatalogModifier[];
  discounts: CatalogDiscount[];
  taxes: CatalogTax[];
  salesTypes: CatalogSalesType[];
}

// export type CatalogEntityKey = keyof CatalogEntity;

export const catalog: CatalogEntity = {
  items: [],
  categories: [],
  modifiers: [],
  discounts: [],
  taxes: [],
  salesTypes: [],
};

export type ArrayType<T> = T extends (infer U)[] ? U : never;

export function appendEntity<
  // K extends CatalogEntityKey,
  V extends ArrayType<CatalogEntity[keyof CatalogEntity]>
>(key: keyof CatalogEntity, value: V): void {
  const index = catalog[key].findIndex((m) => m.id === value.id);

  if (index >= 0) {
    catalog[key][index] = value;
  } else {
    catalog[key].push(value);
  }
}
```

I removed `K`, but putting it back doesn't reprise the warning:

```js
export function appendEntity<
  K extends CatalogEntityKey,
  V extends ArrayType<CatalogEntity[keyof CatalogEntity]>
>(key: K, value: V): void {
  const index = catalog[key].findIndex((m) => m.id === value.id);

  if (index >= 0) {
    catalog[key][index] = value;
  } else {
    catalog[key].push(value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but using base type I cannot get full typing from second argument `value`. I ended up casting `catalog[key] as V[]`

Comment: No problem, just be aware that Type assertions (while acceptable) are not always the safest method https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions:~:text=Reminder%3A%20Because%20type%20assertions%20are%20removed%20at%20compile%2Dtime%2C%20there%20is%20no%20runtime%20checking%20associated%20with%20a%20type%20assertion.%20There%20won%E2%80%99t%20be%20an%20exception%20or%20null%20generated%20if%20the%20type%20assertion%20is%20wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up casting `catalog[key] as V[]`

```
export function appendEntity<K extends CatalogEntityKey, V extends ArrayType<CatalogEntity[K]>>(key: K, value: V): void {
  const entities = catalog[key] as V[]
  const index = entities.findIndex(m => m.id === value.id)
  
  if (index >= 0) {
    entities[index] = value
  } else {
    entities.push(value)
  }
}
```